# Why after search-toggle-case-fold text is select?

Tags: isearch, case-folding

windows 10, emacs 26.1

I want to set I-search case sensitive mode.
Before:

[image]

```
M-x isearch-toggle-case-fold
```

after:

[image]

Now it's search in case sensitive mode. Nice.

But why it select text?

P.S. If I start by `emacs -Q` it's same result:

Here steps of reproduce:

1. Start emacs -Q
2. Input some text
3. `M-x isearch-toggle-case-fold`
4. `C-s` (isearch) HELLO
5. `C-g`
6. `M-x isearch-toggle-case-fold`
7. and see result on step4.jpg

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You've probably had your mark set before you've started to search.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 No, I'm not mark any text

Comment: Do you see this with `emacs -Q`? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: @Drew Yes, I updated my post

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Toggling case-sensitivity should not activate the region. Please consider filing a bug report, `M-x report-emacs-bug`, with a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the problem, starting with `emacs -Q`.

Answer (score 1):

Note, that I assume that `isearch-toggle-case-fold` is not supposed to be run outside of `isearch-mode`.

Cause of the effect:
The highlighting belongs to the overlay stored in variable `isearch-overlay` generated or moved by function `isearch-highlight`.

`isearch-highlight` is called in [`isearch-update`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/9b480db6732c6d2e886838f112d9bd46fc8989bf/lisp/isearch.el#L1336-L1337) which is called in [`isearch-toggle-case-fold`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/9b480db6732c6d2e886838f112d9bd46fc8989bf/lisp/isearch.el#L2026-L2032) generated by [`isearch-define-mode-toggle`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/9b480db6732c6d2e886838f112d9bd46fc8989bf/lisp/isearch.el#L1981).

The reason why `isearch-update` is used in `isearch-define-mode-toggle` is pretty clear. The change of the case sensitivity should have immediate effect.

But that only makes sense when we are in `isearch-mode`.

A conceptual fix would be:

```el
(defun isearch-update-only-in-isearch-mode (fun &rest args)
  (when isearch-mode
    (apply fun args)))

(advice-add 'isearch-update :around #'isearch-update-only-in-isearch-mode)
```

But, maybe `isearch-toggle-case-fold` should actually throw an error when called outside of `isearch-mode`.

Comment: it looks like a bug in Emacs